# How to loop each record in CTE and read column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to loop data in CTE and fetch each record and process based on one column value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_saveVmssMapping]
    (@serverTypes INT = 0,
     @vmsses INT = 0,
     @regions INT = 0,
     @countryList VARCHAR)
AS 
    WITH countryTbl AS
    (
        SELECT value 
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@countryList, ',')
    )
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
    DECLARE @cnt_total INT;
    SET @cnt_total = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM countryTbl;

    WHILE @cnt < cnt_total
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM VmssCountryMapping 
                       WHERE VmssId = @vmsses 
                         AND Country_code = @userName 
                         AND ServerTypeId = @serverTypes)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO VmssCountryMapping (VmssId, Country_code, ServerTypeId) 
            VALUES (@vmsses, @userName, @serverTypes)
        END
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END
```

Here I have created a CTE where I am adding comma separated records. Now I will loop each record and process the insert if it matches the query.

Comment: what makes you think you have to "loop data"?   What is your desired result?   At first glance, I'd say you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how set-based programming should work.

Comment: You have not made a successful transition to working with sets. Nor does your procedure compile - something you should have mentioned. And you made a common mistake - declaring "list" parameter as varchar without a length. This is the same as declaring it varchar(1) - which won't ever work. Your split function returns a table. You simply select from that "table" to insert into VmssCountryMapping using the appropriate exists clause (or use a merge statement instead of an insert statement).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to loop a result, you can simply insert everything at once.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_saveVmssMapping]
(
    @serverTypes INT = 0,
    @vmsses INT = 0,
    @regions INT = 0,
    @countryList VARCHAR(AlwaysAssignALength)
)
AS 
with countryTbl as 
(
 SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@countryList, ',')
)
INSERT INTO VmssCountryMapping (VmssId, Country_code, ServerTypeId) 
SELECT @vmsses, value, @serverTypes 
FROM countryTbl c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM VmssCountryMapping m
                    WHERE m.VmssId = @vmsses 
                    AND m.Country_code = c.value 
                    AND m.ServerTypeId = @serverTypes);
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how it can be inserted at once?  @Luis Cazares

Comment: i just tested ..its not working ..its not inserting any values even table is empty @Luis Cazares

Comment: Now I see, my query does not insert, it just selects. just add the INSERT part between the CTE and the SELECT.

Comment: That't why i asked for insert query .anyways i have resolve it ..Really thanks for your help..